# Copy from vim inside tmux to clipboard

Tags: vim, clipboard, tmux

Outside tmux, I can easily copy to system clipboard by yanking into the `"+` register but inside tmux even copying into `"+` register doesn't help me to access the copied data outside vim (i.e. from system clipboard)

I am using `Vi IMproved 8.0` and `tmux 2.3` on debian based distro.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer to your question. You may consider it as a temporary solution until you get a good answer.

If you enabled mouse support in tmux, you may press and hold `Option` or `Alt`  button and select text to copy to system clipboard.

Comment: Except I don't have a mouse.